# Rolling Back Enhanced Notes and Notes Reporting

Tags: reporting, notes, files, richtext-notes

My client has enabled Enhanced Notes in their org, but are now experiencing all the reporting limitations associated with new feature. They want to pull reports with actual text entered in note, but limited to textpreview field of 255 character in addition to parentid record association and access to files via reports which are known grievances.

I tested "rolling back" Enhanced Notes in dev environment, expecting to see the ContentNote records converted to traditional Note records, but instead, I have lost access to the records and the Notes & Attachments related list.

I noticed that on objects where Notes & Attachments related list was used, prior to when Enhance Notes was enabled, the related list is still available, but for objects where the enhanced notes and its related list were used, the notes & attachments list is not available.

Ultimately, the client wants to create full notes reports, with text and associated record data either via enhanced note or traditional note. Any thoughts on a custom solution to meet requirement/getting back notes & attachments on desired objects?

I have already played around with dataload exporting of feedattachment, contentversion, and contentnote with no satisfaction : (

Comment: enhanced notes are saved with the same object prefix as `ContentVersion` - did you try running a report/soql on those to at least verify their existence?  then also look for `ContentDocumentLinks` to see if you can restore the association to the parent via data loader